# When closures are created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to know that when closures is created in JavaScript

```js
function outerFunc() {
    var a = 2;

    function() {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
    };
    var b = 4;
}

var saveFunc = outerFunc();
saveFunc();
```

Is closures are created before execution of code or closure is created when outerFunc invoked or closures is created when we write innerFunc or closure is created when innerFunc is return from outerFunc and we store innerFunc with closure in saveFunc ?

Comment: when you call `outerFunc()`

Comment: @Thomas that's the way I think about it, but there's an argument to be made that the term really refers to the set of all declared symbols visible to code in a function. That is, as more of a static thing than the allocated memory for an actual call to the function.

Comment: A closure is a function with a reference to the environment it was created in (to be able to resolve free variables). By that definition every function is a closure in JavaScript (implementations might optimize but that's irrelevant to the discussion IMO). Therefore a closure is created when the function definition is evaluated. The inner function definition is not evaluated until `outerFunc` is called.

Comment: @FelixKling is correct. Every function is a closure and it's the *definition* that creates one. Still, slightly more informally, we usually talk about closures when the function actually references something outside, so while `f = a => a + 1` *is* a closure, we tend not to refer it as such and reserve the term for something like `b = 1; f = a => a + b`

Comment: Worth noting at this point maybe that some languages have special syntax for defining closures. E.g. in PHP (up till recently?) you had to write `function()  use ($outerVariable) {}`.

Answer (score 3):

Closures are created at *function definition time*. So, if you have:

```
var a = 1;
function foo() {
  console.log(a);
}
```

This is a closure. It "closes over" the outside variables. In this case `a`. Honestly, the "closes over" never made sense to me (probably does from a different perspective), so I prefer to think of it this way - a function that has access to the outer scope. In this case `a` comes from the outer scope.

This may seem a bit weird because a lot of examples and explanations of closures have something like:

```js
function outer() {
  var a = 1;
  return function inner(b) {//<-----------
    return a + b;           //           |
  }                         //           |
}                           //           |
                            //           |
var add1 = outer();         //           |
                            //           |
console.log(add1.name);     // "inner" ---
console.log(typeof a);      // undefined
console.log(add1(41));      // 42
```

Where the explanation is that `inner` is a closure. It is is *created* as soon as `outer` is executed (definition time for `inner`) and later returned from `outer`. The special property of the closure is that retains reference to the variable `a` which is currently out of scope. This is *true* but it gives the wrong impression. There doesn't need to be an outside reference in the function for it to be a closure. Even a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) like:

```
function add(a, b) {
   return a + b;
}
```

which doesn't use outside references and is entirely self-contained forms a closure at creation.

In short, any function in JavaScript is a closure and has never *not* been.

However, this is slightly more academic. As mentioned, the useful property of closures is that they retain references to the scope they are defined in. So, in practice we usually refer to closures only when this property is used - so, in the example with `inner` and `outer` - *both* have formed closures but we'd focus on `inner` because it actually uses the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:  "a closure is a *thing."*  Specifically, it is a `function()` that has been declared within the body of another function.  You can pass a reference to that function to allow it to be called, and, when you do, it magically will still have access to the variables (such as `a, b` in your example) which were available to it.  That's the magick of closures.

Comment: *"it is a function() that has been declared within the body of another function"* Not just, at least not in the context of JavaScript. Global functions are also closures. Global variables work because functions are closures.

Answer (score 0):

At the outerFunc() creation time.
A closure is created everytime when we create a function.

Please visit this link :[Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

When an inner function uses the outer function's variable, then closer is created in javascript.

```js
// Closure is not created example
function addSquares(a, b) {
    function square(x) {
        return x * x;
    }
    return square(a) + square(b);
}

// Closure is created example
function addSquares(a, b) {
    function square(x) {
        return a * x;
    }
    return square(a) + square(b);
}
```